# Can't create or update records in a loop, using ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

Ruby 2.6.3
Rails 6.0.3

I don't why, when I try to create or update a record in a loop, adding an attachment or attachments, just only one or two recoreds can be updated. I also tested this behaviour with only one attachment and only for creating. But the behaviour is the same.
In the code below, I'm trying to reload attachments on aws, using active storage. But only 1 record is updated.

```
namespace :uploads do
  task migrate_to_active_storage: :environment do
    Upload.where.not(csv_file_name: nil).find_each do |upload|
      %w[csv log].map do |attachment_type|
        attach_url = [
          'https://',
          ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
          ".s3-#{ENV['AWS_REGION']}.amazonaws.com/",
          upload.business.normalized_name,
          '/upload/',
          upload.id.to_s,
          "/#{attachment_type}/",
          upload.csv_file_name
        ].join

        upload.send(attachment_type).attach(
          io: open(attach_url),
          filename: upload["#{attachment_type}_file_name"],
          content_type: upload["#{attachment_type}_content_type"]
        )
      end
    end
    ap 'DONe WITH SUCCESS' # never appears
  end
end
```

I've managed to fix this, using threds. But I don't know why it doesn't work in the code above.
This solution works fine.

```
 namespace :uploads do
  task migrate_to_active_storage: :environment do
    uploads = Thread.new { Upload.ids }.value

    uploads.each do |id|
      Thread.new do
        sleep 2
        upload = Upload.find id

        upload.update csv: get_attachment(upload, 'csv'),
                      log: get_attachment(upload, 'log')
      end.join
    end
  end
end

def get_attachment(upload, attachment_type)
  attachment_url = [
    'https://',
    ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    ".s3-#{ENV['AWS_REGION']}.amazonaws.com/",
    upload.business.normalized_name,
    '/upload/',
    upload.id.to_s,
    "/#{attachment_type}/",
    upload["#{attachment_type}_file_name"]
  ].join

  {
    io: open(attachment_url),
    filename: "#{upload.id}_#{upload["#{attachment_type}_file_name"]}",
    content_type: upload["#{attachment_type}_content_type"]
  }
end
```

And what is really a mystic. When I try to call a differen model, for instance, like User. And even if it does nothing, the code above won't work. Only 1 record will'be updated.

Comment: There is also another difference in the two code snippets you gave: The first one uses `attach`, the second one `update`. Can you confirm that the second (threaded) example also DOES NOT work if you remove the thread stuff (but keep the `get_attachment` and `update` calls)?

Comment: Felix, Yes, It doesn't work, if I remove threads.
I've just updated the example below, adding sleep. If wont work without thid delay.

The behaviour you can reproduce just creating a new rails project v 6  and initializing active storage. And then just try to attach something to your record in a loop.  Like 

YourRecord..find_each do |record|
  record.attachable_field.attach( 
  io: StringIO.new('hello world'),,
  filename: "random name #{record.id}",
  cotent_type: 'plain/text'
)
end

It won't work anyway